# How to construct a matrix based on user input?

Tags: python, matrix, input

How to solve the problem to create a matrix with random numbers (user input)?
I also how a problem with this:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   23: ordinal not in range(128)

```
array = list()
i = int(input("How many row: "))      
j = int(input("How many column: "))    


for x in range(i):                
    if i <= 0 or i>10:
        print("Failure!")  
        break
    elif j <= 0 or j>10:
        print("Failure!")
        break
    else:
        for y in range(j):        
            num = raw_input("Value: ")       
            array.append(int(num))


a = np.reshape((i,j))
print a
```

Comment: What is random about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `np.reshape((i,j))` to `a = np.reshape(array,(i,j))` and it works fine. I dont see any error in the code like you mentioned.

```
import numpy as np
array = list()
i = int(input("How many row: "))
j = int(input("How many column: "))


for x in range(i):
    if i <= 0 or i>10:
         print("Failure!")
         break
    elif j <= 0 or j>10:
         print("Failure!")
         break
    else:
        for y in range(j):
             num = raw_input("Value: ")
             array.append(int(num))


a = np.reshape(array,(i,j))
print a
```

Comment: Many many thanks to you! :D So simple but i couldn't find it for hours :)